# No login prompt on greeter

Tags: release-juno, greeter

My apologies if this has been asked. I looked and found a couple questions that could be similar, but not exactly the same, at least as described. After closing the lid on my laptop and suspending and then opening the lid, i have a greeter screen where the mouse moves and the top bar is present with the power icon from which I can either Suspend or Shutdown and from which I can successfully restart. There are other icons present, I've forgotten which they are, and assume they are those normally present on the greeter screen. There is no card with a login prompt. Simply entering my password despite that does nothing. To be as clear as possible without a picture, I have a dark gray background, top bar, and mouse pointer. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: can you make a picture with your phone to show what is going on? I have tried to set the lock option when the computer is suspended and when it returns from suspend it is a normal greeter with the cards of the users plus notification (a tick sign) of the one that is logged in and of course an option to type the password to log in back.

Comment: It hasn't happened after it happened a few times that day. If it does, I will get a picture.

Comment: I've added a pic. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: No worries for the delay. It looks like you have another display attached and the icons are there.. I can't lock my computer for some reason so I can't help you, hope the problem will resolve by itself again - it happens sometimes

Comment: No, no other display attached.

Comment: Mhm, sometimes when loading the os the screen of my laptop is black until the greeter, and if I attach external monitor the elementary logo is there.. So it acts like there is one attached no matter that there is not. What I see in your picture is the same like if there is attached another display and the login boxes are there..

Comment: Is the top bar still there in your case?

Comment: During the plymouth (only elementary logo flashing on the screen) - no, but when the login screen is loaded and if I have another monitor attached,  when I move the mouse to one or the other screen, the login boxes do move to the monitor where the mouse cursor is, but the top bar stays fixed only on the primary monitor. That's why your screenshot somehow reminds me of that.